# Mysqli Procedural Insert Into Table not working

Tags: php, insert, mysqli

I am trying to insert into a table with Procedural Mysqli. It is not posting any errors nor is it posting the information to the database. Here is my code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Accounts (FirstName, LastName, Username, Password, Access) VALUES ({$_POST['FirstNameTbx']}, {$_POST['LastNameTbx']}, {$_POST['UsernameTbx']}, {$_POST['PasswordTbx']}, {$_POST['AccessDDL']})";
        mysqli_query($link, $query);
        mysqli_close($link);
        $Error .= "$query";
```

Update:
I changed to prepared statement, now I am getting:

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /home/bryantrx/public_html/ec/add_user.php on line 19

There are only 5 variables that need to be bound, and the UserID auto increments, so it doesn't need to be bound or referenced in the statement..

```
if ($stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO Accounts (FirstName, LastName, Username, Password, Access) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")){
            $stmt->bind_param($_POST['FirstNameTbx'], $_POST['LastNameTbx'], $_POST['UsernameTbx'], $_POST['PasswordTbx'], $_POST['AccessDDL']);
            $stmt->execute();   
            $Error .= "success";
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            echo $link->error;
        }
```

Comment: You're not asking it for any errors, so it's not giving you any... the reason is the same as in your [last post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569113/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-query-on-a-non-object-in). Do not directly inject POST values into the query string, it's dangerous

Comment: I could show what you did wrong in this query, but the real solution is to use prepared queries and it will solve the problem better.

Comment: can you please show me what I did wrong here. I have $link declared on another page which I am including in a line above it.

Comment: You didn't quote the values in the `VALUES` clause.

Comment: If you use prepared queries, you don't need to worry about quoting.

Comment: I updated my post to reflect my prepared statement.

Comment: @n_starnes updated my answer - you need to specify the types of parameters you are binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an error message you need to call [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php):

```
$error = mysqli_error($link);
```

You would also make life easier (and more secure) for yourself if you built your queries using [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

```php
$query = "INSERT INTO Accounts (FirstName, LastName, Username, Password, Access) 
            VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

if ($stmt = mysqli_stmt_prepare($link, $query)) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", 
                $_POST['FirstNameTbx'], 
                $_POST['LastNameTbx'], 
                $_POST['UsernameTbx'], 
                $_POST['PasswordTbx'], 
                $_POST['AccessDDL']);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        $error = mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

} else {
    $error = mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

**UPDATE** - ok, you've swapped to OO which is fine. When using [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) the first parameter describes the data you are binding. In this case if it is five strings, you would put 5 "s" like so:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", 
           $_POST['FirstNameTbx'], 
           $_POST['LastNameTbx'], 
           $_POST['UsernameTbx'], 
           $_POST['PasswordTbx'], 
           $_POST['AccessDDL']);
```

Comment: I literally just noticed this. I did need to do a prepared but forgot the "sssss". thank you.